# Get clicked date(s) in FullCallendar

Tags: listview, fullcalendar

Good morning, I am using FullCalendar in list view, with daily recurring events, the problem is that when I press the event, I need to somehow tell me what day it is, and pass that in a link to be able to show the history of that day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the dates (start and end) of the clicked event.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.start);
    console.log(info.event.end);
}
```